# Java regex for consecutively repeated letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: java, regex

I have to apply a password policy and I am using this Regex (default to my Identity Server) which accepts password as a combination of lower case, upper case, number and special character:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])).{0,100}$
```

I need to modify it so that it should not match string having more than 3 consecutive copies of the same character, as in e.g. `Adminnnn@123`.

Comment: Rather than making it needlessly complex, why not just apply two regex's?

Comment: your regex is not working for me.

Comment: Asterisk sign was missed Sorry for that. Here is the right one - ^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])).{0,100}$

Comment: Instead of solving this with a regular expression consider just coding up these rules in code. Regular expressions are quite hard to decode when reading code. Also if the rules change at some point its not trivial to know what part of the regex it is safe to change. In case you are going the regex route for performance reasons (seems unlikely) ensure you actually measure that it is faster...

Comment: @EmilH Thanks for the suggestion and valid point but in my case, I don't have option to change the code. I can only use properties file to put this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was tricky, but I think this should work ([try it out live here](https://regex101.com/r/fN3eR1/29)):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])(?!.*(.)\1\1\1)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&*]{0,100}$
```

I am using a 4 lookahead assertions and one negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?=.*[0-9])         must contain a number 
(?=.*[a-z])         must contain a lower case
(?=.*[A-Z])         must contain an upper case
(?=.*[!@#$%&*])     must contain a special character
(?!.*(.)\1\1\1)     must not repeat the character in group 1 more than 3 times
[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&*]  is composed of these characters
{0,100}             0 to 100 symbols allowed
```

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&*]` is not required. replace it with `.`

Comment: @TheScientificMethod i think its typical of a lot of password to not have whitespace, or do things like allow characters which use weird ascii. Might mess up depending on the encoding of the string.

Comment: i see that is for a reason.

Comment: I also think that putting . will allow other special characters and whitespaces in password that might violate password policy, but ya thanks for the suggestion.